# placing mean,total and max together in a table in r

Tags: r

I have some simple commands looking into totals, means and maximums of a variable whilst another variable is an assigned value:

```
sum(data[data$var1==1,]$var2)
mean(data[data$var1==1,]$var2)
max(data[data$var1==1,]$var2)
```

Is there a way to put this into a nice table which doesn't mean my output is in scattered lines?  ldeally, to make it even more complex, would be to structure the table around the different values of var1 (1 thru 5 in my case) so I could have the mean, max and total of var 2 for each value of var1.

This is probably a bit above where I'm at with R right now: I'm a pure novice.  Some help would be appreciated though.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend checking out the `data.table` package, which is like a beefed-up version of data frames.  One thing it does really well (and quickly, if you have a lot of data) is summaries like this.

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(mtcars)[, list(sum=sum(mpg), mean=mean(mpg), max=max(mpg)),
                      by=cyl][order(cyl)]
#   cyl   sum     mean  max
#1:   4 293.3 26.66364 33.9
#2:   6 138.2 19.74286 21.4
#3:   8 211.4 15.10000 19.2
```

If you want to summarize by more than one variable, just use something like `by=list(cyl,vs,otherColumnNamesHere)`.

Comment: Thanks ever so much, that's certainly the easiest package and the code makes complete sense.  I'm a real novice and learning as I go, and I can completely decipher this command using that package.  Very useful.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the tables package, read through the vignette for the package shows how to do exactly what you are asking for.

```
> tabular( ( factor(cyl) + 1) ~ mpg * (sum + mean + max), data=mtcars )

             mpg             
 factor(cyl) sum   mean  max 
 4           293.3 26.66 33.9
 6           138.2 19.74 21.4
 8           211.4 15.10 19.2
 All         642.9 20.09 33.9
```

Comment: I will never understand this algebra :(

Comment: @baptiste, it is always harder to understand what is not there.  So maybe your confusion comes from the fact that there is no algebra and you are trying to understand something more complicated than what is there :-).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `cbind` for that.

```
cbind(sum(data[data$var1==1,]$var2),mean(data[data$var1==1,]$var2),max(data[data$var1==1,]$var2))
```

Example using mtcars data

```
mydata<-mtcars  
  l<-cbind(sum(mydata[mydata$cyl==4,]$mpg),mean(mydata[mydata$cyl==4,]$mpg),max(mydata[mydata$cyl==4,]$mpg))
l<-data.frame(l)
names(l)<-c("sum","mean","max")
> l
    sum     mean  max
1 293.3 26.66364 33.9
```

There is a `ddply` function from plyr package that does all for each categories of var1 (here cyl)

```
library(plyr)
ddply(mydata,.(cyl),summarize, sum=sum(mpg),mean=mean(mpg), max=max(mpg))

 ddply(mydata,.(cyl),summarize, sum=sum(mpg),mean=mean(mpg), max=max(mpg))
  cyl   sum     mean  max
1   4 293.3 26.66364 33.9
2   6 138.2 19.74286 21.4
3   8 211.4 15.10000 19.2
```