# creating tables from 'mini tables' in r

Tags: r

I've got some code below which I'd like to be able to combine into one big table.  Is this possible?

```
cbind(sum(michelson[michelson$Expt==1,]$Speed),
      mean(michelson[michelson$Expt==1,]$Speed),
      max(michelson[michelson$Expt==1,]$Speed))    

cbind(sum(michelson[michelson$Expt==2,]$Speed), 
      mean(michelson[michelson$Expt==2,]$Speed),
      max(michelson[michelson$Expt==2,]$Speed))    

cbind(sum(michelson[michelson$Expt==3,]$Speed),
      mean(michelson[michelson$Expt==3,]$Speed),
      max(michelson[michelson$Expt==3,]$Speed))    

cbind(sum(michelson[michelson$Expt==4,]$Speed),
      mean(michelson[michelson$Expt==4,]$Speed),
      max(michelson[michelson$Expt==4,]$Speed))   

cbind(sum(michelson[michelson$Expt==5,]$Speed),
      mean(michelson[michelson$Expt==5,]$Speed),
      max(michelson[michelson$Expt==5,]$Speed))
```

I'd appreciate some help please from some experts!  Thanks

Comment: Sorry about the formatting of the code.  It's basically the same thing repeated 5 times, controlling for Expt 1 thru 5 in each separate section.

Comment: I edited the layout. Please click edit and look what was done. If you'll look at the formatting help http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help, people will be more inclined to help!

Comment: What's wrong with just using one `cbind`?

Comment: Would one cbind work for the entire thing, in the sense of having 5 rows showing expt 1 2, 3 etc?  Sorry, very new to R.

Comment: If you want them below each other, just put an `rbind( )` around them. You might want to read a basic R tutorial, it will help a lot.

Comment: Also, maybe add some example data. How many rows and columns does michelson have? There are functions like colSums and rowSums, colMeans and rowMeans, that exactly do what you'd expect.

Comment: Michelson has 100 rows and 3 columns in its original form.  I want 3 columns showing total, mean and max Speed, and 5 rows which correspond to whether these values were taken from experiment 1,2,3,4 or 5.  Also possible is that rows 1-20 are expt1, 21-40 expt2 and so on, so it could be done that way.

Comment: Why don't you use the `ddply` answer already given to you [here]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18553393/placing-mean-total-and-max-together-in-a-table-in-r)?

Comment: -1: for asking the same question where answers already exists for base R, plyr, and data.table

Comment: Sorry about that.  Apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explaining what you are trying to achieve will help someone answer rather than pasting only the code ... From what I can understand from your code, ddply seems to be a right choice here as pointed out by @Henrik

Comment: I used the data.table solution that was given to me dnlbrky in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18553393/placing-mean-total-and-max-together-in-a-table-in-r